# Masonry - How do I arrange varied width divs horizontally first then vertically?

Tags: javascript, masonry

I have a series of divs whose class names are called item (I have two width categories).  Two are 640px and the rest are 320px.  I want to arrange them horizontally first then vertically using the masonry library.

When I run the following initialization code each of the smaller divs is not fitting in the white space.   I can not get masonry to fit different amount of divs as compared to the first row.

How can I fix my issue so that the smaller divs are side by side?

Here is my initialization code.  I can post more code if needed to address the issue.

```
 $('#gridDiv').masonry({
                itemSelector: '.item',
                isAnimated: true,
                isFitWidth: true,
            });
```

[image: Varied width divs]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up grabbing the latest build of Masonry and applied the following changes below to remedy the issue.  It works now.

As referenced from:

http://masonry.desandro.com/options.html#columnwidth

If columnWidth is not set, Masonry will use the outer width of the first element.

In my case the first element's width was why all other elements were being distributed in the way described in my question.

CSS

```
.small {
    width: 290px; /*This is the width of the small div element of the div I want to size according to*/
}
```

JS

```
       $('#gridDiv').masonry({
            itemSelector: '.item',
            columnWidth: '.small', //Reference the .small class selector to set width
            isAnimated: true,
            isFitWidth: true,
        });
```